# nginx pagination with variables rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm using wordpress and I got [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56848/wp-list-categories-pagination#57404) working to get and paginate subcategories of a specific category.

It works (almost) fine because it creates me two problems that can be solved on nginx.

### The first problem with this pagination:

The way the pagination is working creates a duplicate content issue by paginating two times the first page with two different urls;

- `domain.com/cat-variable-name/`
- `domain.com/cat-variable-name/?cpage=1`

When someone returns to "**?cpage=1**", it should be redirected to:

```
domain.com/cat-variable-name/
```

### The second problem:

These are not SEO friendly URL's and I do have a custom permalinks with **/%postname%/** but it does not rewrite this custom pagination and I have no clue on how to it without breaking anything else on my site. So...

After page one `domain.com/cat-variable-name/?cpage=(page_number)`

I need to find a way to rewrite all of to something like this:

```
domain.com/cat-variable-name/cpage/(page_number)
```

How can I do this?

#### These are the ones that I tried and failed:

I already tried these without success:

`rewrite ^/?cpage=$1 /cpage/([^/]*)/;`

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^(.+)\?cpage=1$) { 
set $dom_prefix $1; set $args ''; rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$dom_prefix permanent; break; } 
if ($request_uri ~* ^(.+)\?cpage=(\d+)$) { 
set $dom_prefix $1; set $cpage $2; set $args ''; rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$dom_prefix/p$cpage permanent; break; }
```

Note: Please keep in mind that **"cat-variable-name"** and **"page_number"** never are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx `$request_uri` does not contain query arguments, it only contains the URI. Query argumants are available in `$arg_name` variables.

You can try this:

```
if ($arg_cpage = 1) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$uri;
    break;
}

if ($arg_cpage ~ ^(\d+)$) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$uri/p$1;
    break;
}
```

Comment: @Tero-Kikanen this is causing too many redirects on this link: domain.com/cat-variable-name/?cpage=1 This also does't rewrites these urls... Any ideias on the cause?

Comment: The cause was actually using `$request_uri`. Replacing it with `$uri` like above should help. Also, `return` is faster to use here.

Comment: @Tero-Kikanen the `domain.com/cat-variable-name/?cpage=1` now redirects just perfect, and that solves a great part of my problem! The remaining problem now is on the second block of the code that returns a 404 page although I guess that is not a problem generated by your answer... Can you please point my out a possible reason for it?

Comment: Can you access the URL `domain.com/cat-variable-name/p10` normally? Or is the original `p` character an error in your original example?

Comment: @Tero-Kikanen I get a 404 page for `domain.com/cat-variable-name/p10` so, ...It's an error ...sorry. Should I replace the `p$1` for `cpage$1` or just `$1`?

Comment: It depends on the URL where the page can be found, that is, it depends on your setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45435/discussion-between-alex-and-tero-kilkanen).